# Trouble making editable letterhead template in Word

Tags: template

I'm having quite the headache tying to figure out how to make the header of my letterhead template editable in Word 365 and considering my other options.

I wanted to ask is, for documents with more than 1 page, is it standard to have the letterhead on all pages, or just the first?

Answer (score 3):

For stationery, the convention is to have the full letterhead (logo, company name, address/phone/URL etc., header and footer) on the first page, and second and subsequent pages have reduced branding — maybe just the logo and company name.

In Word, you have to create a two-page template with a new Section. Your first page is your full letterhead; your second page starts the new Section with the reduced branding.

You can release it to the client as 1-Page Letterhead and 2-Page Letterhead, so they can use whichever they need.

Answer (score 0):

Sections control pretty much all workflow changes with stylistic functions in Word. She is a tricky beast - YouTube has some good resources if you want to learn more. I will post up some useful links when I'm on a desktop.